# problem in copy string for other class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, copy, nsmutablestring

In my app I am sending a request to the web server and getting some results, then I am parsing this result and storing this result string into other class object string.

For example:

```
@interface GraphView : UIViewController<UITabBarControllerDelegate> {  

NSMutableString *graphTempString;   

}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *graphTempString;   
@end
```

TSUClass .m

```
implementing NSURLConnection(),  
connectionDidFinishLoading(),

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName
attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict()  

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{  
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"statusTEResult"])  
    {  
        tempString=soapResults;   
        if (grpahCall == YES) {         
            graphViewController=[[GraphView alloc]init];   
            graphViewController.graphTempString=tempString;  

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:graphViewController animated:YES];  
        }
```

When I am debugging I can see the value of `graphViewController.graphTempString` but after going to GraphView, I am not able to see the values.

I hope some one know how to solve this issue.

Comment: How do you know resultString isn't nil as well?

Comment: I tried with NSLog(resultString);and also in debugger I can see the value of reslutString

Comment: What does your property look like in your .h file for 2ndClassObj ?

Comment: also when i am copying into tempString on debugger I can see the value in tempString but when i am in 2ndClass by using   [self.navigationController pushViewController:2nClassObj animated:YES]; and i am checking value of tempSting its show "nil"

Comment: in .h file 2ndClass *2ndClassObj;

Comment: have u created the property of NSString like this @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *tempString;

Comment: yes, @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *tempString;

Comment: make it simple NSString. i think resultstring is also NSString. it may create the peoblem.and i aslo gave esy solution to pass the value.

Comment: @DavidM - I assume that's already been done? The OP has looked at resultString in the debugger?

Comment: If resultString is an NSString and your property is an NSMutableString don't you get a compiler warning when you build your code?

Comment: i am using only NSMutableString and my resultString is also NSMutableString

Comment: OK,can you post your real code instead - there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted in the question so it must be something else!

Comment: mainClass .h file "NSUmtableString *resultStirng" then i set @property and @synthesize in .m file, also in 2ndClass file .h "NSUmtableString *tempStirng" also set @property and @synthesize in .m file then in ,main class .m file i am creating object for 2nd class 2nClassObj = [[2ndClass alloc]init];  
2nClassObj.tempString = resultString;  
[self.navigationController pushViewController:2nClassObj animated:YES];

Comment: 2nClassObj.tempString =[NSMutableString stringWithString:resultString];

Comment: @Pooja - you can edit your question to put the code in - and you can't start a class name with a number so that's still not your real code. The code you've put in your question is correct so the error is somewhere else in your code - without the real code we can't help you!

Comment: ok, i will do it give me 20 mins thanks for advice

Comment: what a mess... That's what happens when a question is not well formulated and/or with enough details...! :)

Comment: graphViewController.graphTempString=self.tempString;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to pass value.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:resultString forKey:@"resultString"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and in another class use this value like this

```
NSString *resultString=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"resultString"];
```

or u may do it like this.

```
graphViewController.graphTempString=self.tempString;
```

Comment: How is this better than a property?

Comment: There's a problem with this that's not immediately obvious. What happens if you do this for every variable that you need to pass around? You will fill up your NSUserDefaults which will cause your app to startup slower etc. You also run the risk of reusing the same name for variables by mistake i.e. what if you had a 3rdClass that also wanted to pass around a 'resultString'?

Comment: i agree with deanWomboume, i tried with NSUserDefaults I feel its very slow

Comment: no way its not slow at all... u can use this value anywhere in the application. its best future. if its slow then why apple provide this kind of feature.

Comment: It's for storing values between different runs of the app. Not for just passing variables between classes. That's why @property exists!

Comment: @rkloves, NSUserDefault is working perfectly for me thank you very much but still i am eager to know why its not happening with property

Comment: @rkloves But your answer uses NSUserDefaults, something designed for a different purpose and it uses it badly. And there is obviously something wrong with the original code and you make no attempt to find it!

Comment: @deanWombourne we can save array also in NSUserDefaults. its of-course used for store value and used it whenever we want to use.. we can save username password that kind of things. we can save game state. nothing wrong in this.

Comment: @pooja i have to check your whole code. u did something else mistake. u can send me ur code to my email. or you can use NSUserDefaults its also easy way. thnx for accepting my answer.

Comment: @Rakesh Yes, between runs of the app it's perfect. (though it's not secure so perhaps not passwords!) But just to pass an NSString between two objects its absolutely the wrong thing to do :)

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
2nClassObj.tempString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",resultString];
```

good luck

Comment: did you try to nslog tempstring before pushing, is you tempstring being allocated?

Comment: i set the property, should i have to allocate too like tempString=[[NSMutableSting alloc]init];?

Comment: if you have not initialize the string then yes you have to,in your 2ndClass.m `-(id) init { if(self=[super init]) { tempString=[[NSMutabaleString alloc]init];] } return self; }` try this

Answer (score 0):

@Pooja i suggest you to try doing this by making a variable in `AppDelegate` class give your `resultString` to this variable and then fetch the value from this variable in your `2ndClass` or in any class you want .....you will never get null value.

Lets suppose the object of your `AppDelegate` class is `appDelegate` and the variable which of `NSString` type is lets `stringValue`. Then in your class where you are getting the `resultString` do like this.

```
appDelegate.stringValue = resultString;
```

And in your `2ndClass` class take the value from this variable like this.

```
tempString =  appDelegate.stringValue;
```

You will get the data.....Hope you got my point.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add some NSLog statements?

```
    if (grpahCall == YES) {
        graphViewController=[[GraphView alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"-%@-", tempString);
        graphViewController.graphTempString=tempString;  
        NSLog(@"-%@-", graphViewcontroller.graphTempString);

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:graphViewController animated:YES];  
    }
```

I would expect to see the same thing output twice? Can you tell me what you get in the console?

Comment: application is crashed with Error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GraphView setGraphTempString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6363220' after graphViewController.graphTempString=tempString;

Comment: Wow. that's not what I expected at all! It's trying to call setGraphTempString which shoudld work fine - it looks like there is something wrong with your graphTempString property - can you add GraphView .h file to the question please?

Comment: OK, that .h file looks fine. I assume you also have `@synthesize graphTempString` in your GraphView.m file?

Comment: OK, I give up - as far as I can see you are doing everything absolutely correctly. I can't think of anything else to try without actually having your code on my machine and running it myself in the debugger :( When you do find out what's going wrong can you update the question with the solution - I'm really interested to see what's going on! Thanks.

Comment: @deanWomboume, can you advice me for my Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579054/need-suggession-for-access-file