# need suggession for access file

Tags: iphone, file, filesystems, download, unzip

In my app i have one use case "Download Folder(s)" from web server this folder is in zip format.
This folder contains : text files and more zip folder(s)
So my Question is

1. should i just download this folder and user will manage it by himself(like unzip it and open files)
   OR
2. Should I make view like table and put folder name which are downloaded recently(just names no unzip and no open files) 
   OR
3. folder name in table format and if user press on any folder name(i.e cell in table) unzip folder and new view (table view) with file names and zip folder(as main folder contains both files and zip folder in it) (here unzip but not open files)
   OR
4. Option 3 unzip all files and folder and if user click on any specific file open that files(unzip and open files)

right now i am just doing option 1.

also I am doing my master project so the answers from experience users will help me a lot
Thank you

Comment: i am not much experience for iphone but i have knowledge on other programming..my suggestion is option 3(no 4)is good for user...i hope u know how to unzip..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with AAAAAAAAA - number 3 in the minimum I would expect the app to do.

Ideally, you should unzip when they press a file and display the contents but don't open any files automatically.

However, if they press on a file that is unzipped already, you should try to open it - don't open them automatically when you unzip, open them when the user asks for it to be opened :)