# Problem with NSMutableString object declared as extern

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

in my app i need to pass a NSMutableString from one class to another so i put it extern.The problem is that when i run the app, the class does only access the string once, the second time the app crashes !! Obviously the NSMutablString becames nil after the first access. So i tried to figure out something: i converted the string into a C char. Well this time the app doesn't crash, but.. the value of the char changes everytime i call it !!
Am really confused: Please i need to know

1. Is there any way to maintain the value of the NSMutablString so it would be available everytime a class calls it ?
2. What causes the changing in the char's value ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you post some code? It would help a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565438/problem-in-copy-string-for-other-class may be this help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing some weird thing, really.

- If you want to pass the NSMutableString instance from one object (source) to another (target), you should either assign it to the target object's property, or pass it via some method call.
- The target object should **retain** this instance (either explicitly, or using 'retain' flag of the property), to ensure the instance is valid regardless of what the source object does. The target object should also release it, when it is no longer needed, otherwise you'd introduce a memory leak.
- It is not really obvious, that "NSMutableString (pointer) becomes nil". Any invalid reference can lead to a crash when dereferenced, not only nil. Actually, my guess is that you're trying to access a deleted object.
- I guess you've used [NSMutableString cStringUsingEncoding:] or similar method to get char pointer. Keep in mind that the pointer returned is valid for a limited time, check the docs.

Anyway, this is all pretty basic stuff. You should read [Memory Management Progamming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) and make sure you understand everything. It's simply essential to develop a stable Objective-C code.

Comment: thanks i just needed to add the retain property  [myString retain]  its working fine now